# Data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Varchar values that are numbers, and I want them to be decimal values. I'm getting an error saying Error converting data type varchar to numeric. I've tried:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(MYCOLUMN AS decimal(10, 2)), 2)

FROM TABLE
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE


ALTER  COLUMN MYCOLUMN DECIMAL(10,2)
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE


MODIFY COLUMN ACQ_FIELD_8 DECIMAL(10,2)
```

and

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(MYCOLUMN, 'NULL') AS NUMERIC(10,2)), 0)

FROM MYTABLE
```

and I keep getting the same error. I looked the through the data to look for any special characters or letters by using:

```
SELECT MYCOLUMN FROM MYTABLE

WHERE MYCOLUMN LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%'

or MYCOLUMN LIKE '%[(]%'  --etc for each character.
```

The only thing that I have found is that every value for some reason has a `'^'` in it, but when I replace the `'6'` with nothing, the value still can't be converted to a decimal or numeric. If I try ordering the column by number (< 0.00), I get `Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric`.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: First of all: remove the ALL CAPS from the title. It's already bold, no need for shouting.

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error means that you have values too large.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a varchar column in the first place?

Comment: Haha sorry this is my first time posting. So I found out that the problem is that the all the negative values had parenthesis around them, and I thought SQL Server recognized them as negatives. Thanks again fellas

Comment: `SELECT CAST('(123.45)' AS NUMERIC(5,2))` gives  `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.` doesn't mention anything about overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select round(try_convert(decimal(10,2), Mycolumn),2)
```

looks like you have some values which can not be converted to decimal. try_convert will convert them as NULL

Answer (score 1):

You can try isnumeric:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(MYCOLUMN AS decimal(10, 2)), 2)
FROM TABLE
WHERE isnumeric(MYCOLUMN) = 1
```